# How to use zone.js in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, zone

I would like to use zone.js in my Angular project ( not just the runOutsideAngularZone function ).

I tried to include it like this:

```
import { zone } from 'zone.js';
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

```
error TS2306: File 'C:/projects/MyApp/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.d.ts' is not a module.
```

Then I removed the `{ zone }` part:

```
import 'zone.js';
```

But now I get this error:

```
error TS2552: Cannot find name 'zone'. Did you mean 'Zone'?
```

My code is this:

```
    let myZoneSpec = {
        beforeTask: function () {
            console.log('Before task');
        },
        afterTask: function () {
            console.log('After task');
        }
    };
    let myZone = zone.fork(myZoneSpec);
    myZone.run(() => {console.log('Task');});
```

If I replace `żone` with `Zone`, I get this:

```
error TS2339: Property 'fork' does not exist on type 'ZoneType'.
```

How could I import and use zone.js from Angular?

Answer (score 8):

Angular has a wrapper class for **Zone.js** called **ngZone**. You can inject it into your component like any service.

```
    constructor(private zone: NgZone) { 
       this.zone.run(() => { console.log('This is zone'});
     }
```

However, with this approach, we cannot use the full functionality of **zone.js**. For that, we have to declare:

```
declare let Zone: any;
public class MyComponent {
  constructor() {
        Zone.current.fork({
            name: 'myZone'
          }).run(() => {
            console.log('in myzone? ', Zone.current.name);
          });
    }
}
```

Also, the APIs have changed since v 0.6.0. For running beforeTask and afterTask, you can look about it [here](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/334), however, I looked into it and was unable to find anything related to **beforeTask** and **afterTask**.

**Updated**
For running **beforeTask** and **afterTask**, this is how it is possible in the new API.

```
constructor() {
    const parentZone = new Zone();
    const childZone = parentZone.fork({
      name: 'child',
      onInvoke: (...args) => { 
                 console.log('invoked\n', args);
                 const valueToReturn = args[3](); // Run the function provided in the Zone.run
                 console.log('after callback is run');
                 return valueToReturn;
              }
    });
   console.log(childZone.run(() => {console.log('from run'); return 'from child run';}));

}
```

**NOTE:**
If you want to create a **scheduleMicroTask** and want to have same functionality in it also, then you will need to implement **onInvokeTask** and/or **onScheduleTask** in the ZoneSpec (inside the parentZone.fork()).

```
constructor() {
   const parentZone = new Zone();
    const childZone = parentZone.fork({
      name: 'child',
      onScheduleTask: (...args) => {
        console.log('task schedule...\n', args);
        return args[3];
      },
      onInvokeTask: (...args) => {
        console.log('task invoke...\n', args);
        return args[3].callback();
      }
    });

    const microTask = childZone
                      .scheduleMicroTask(
                        'myAwesomeMicroTask',
                        () => { 
                                console.log('microTask is running'); 
                                return 'value returned from microTask'; 
                            } );
    console.log(microTask.invoke());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how to use beforeTask and afterTask? Maybe runGuarded is the solution, but the signature of the function in the docs is messy (`runGuarded<T>(fn: (...args: any[]) => T, applyThis?: any, applyArgs?: any[]): T`), and I am not able to find useful examples

Comment: I would like to call a function before and after each task. That's why I would like to use zones

Comment: @IterAtor I have updated the answer for the latest API. Just remember, choose either of the mentioned solutions but not both otherwise, your function/task will be executed multiple times

Answer (score -1):

I Highly recommend you to use NgZone with Angular.
[Documentation here](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone)

Comment: Thank you, but I am not able to find any usable example code. If I search for ngZone, all I can find is how to use the runOutsideAngular function